# how to list filenames and durations of a various audio files on a server using PHP

Tags: php, audio, ffmpeg

I have a folder full of audio files,  a mix of mostly wma, mp3, wav, but also some obscure files like DS2 and aiff, on a VPS. The folder updates every day.

I am running a php based website using apache and MYSQL.

Is there anyway I can extract or somehow display a list of the audio files along with file durations for each?

I ideally need a solution that would allow a relatively non technical person to extract the data on a daily basis. So I'm thinking of displaying the data via a php file?

Comment: My title was inaccurate. I'm not just looking for mp3, but other formats too.  Thus it's not a duplicate. Also the question incorporates how to parse the data in bulk.

Answer (score 0):

To get the MP3 duration, you have to use a custom class, because PHP doesn't have a builtin function doing that, i suggest you this one [MP3File](http://www.zedwood.com/article/php-calculate-duration-of-mp3): .

After that you have to get all MP3s on the folder and display the name and duration:

```
require_one("mp3file.class.php");

if ($handle = opendir($dir)) { // $dir = your directory path
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
    $mp3file = new MP3File($file);
    $duration1 = $mp3file->getDurationEstimate();//(faster) for CBR only
    $duration2 = $mp3file->getDuration();//(slower) for VBR (or CBR)
        echo $file." - ". MP3File::formatTime($duration2)."\n"; // $duration1 for faster perfs
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
```

Comment: Thanks that's useful. I'm wondering if there is a similar class that covers more audio formats?